# How do you create a Share Extension in iOS8 without a share UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, ios-extensions

I was using Pocket and they seem to have created a share extension that simply posts the URL to their service w/o a UI.

Anyone have an idea on how to replicate this? I'm new to extensions but very familiar with iOS/Objective-C

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Figured it out.

Just don't use the built in SLComposeServiceViewController

```
@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

And make sure to call the following function when done with the share extension

```
[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
```

In other words, replace the contents of `ShareViewController.swift` with:

```
import UIKit

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be amazing to extend your answer with the complete example. Mayn thanks

Comment: Any example of this? if i do the same thing i keeps an overlay ontop of safari which cant be dismissed

Comment: Calling `completeRequest(returningItems:completionHandler:)` from `viewDidLoad()` didn't work for me in iOS 16, but calling it in `viewDidAppear(_:)` did work.

Answer (score 0):

handle extension as per below below in share extension's viewdidload: works

```
[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:blah];
```